# Configuring eclipse to delete logs before tomcat server startup

Tags: eclipse, tomcat5.5

I am using Galileo with tomcat 5.5 server. I want to delete the logs from specific folder every time I start the server. Instead of doing this manually , can i automate this process ? What I need is when i click on the start in eclipse, before start up, the logs should get deleted. How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Eclipse is the right tool to accomplish that. In my current project server start and application deployment is managed by Ant and include a Task to erase Logs between this processes is trivial.

Ant integrates nicelly with Eclipse and Tomcat. You can do the same with Maven if you prefer